# Code formatting with NP++

Tags: formatting, editor, notepad++

Is there a way to format code based on languages in notepad++?
I like how light-weight that editor is, and the syntax highlighting is awesome too. But I'd like to be able to press CTRL+F or something and have everything be nicely lined up, like in some bigger editors.

Comment: Duplicate from [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/58884/auto-format-document-with-notepad). It's TextFX > Edit > Reindent C++ Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some plugins that format source. Check out Plugins -> Plugins Manager -> Show Plugin Manager.